# Windows 8 safe mode grub 2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, grub2, safe-mode

I need to boot into safe mode in Windows 8 Ultimate to un-install Avira as this is not supported in windows 8. The problem is I have also installed Ubuntu 12.04 and from the grub 2, I do not get the option to boot into windows 8 safe mode. 
I do not have the CD/DVD of windows 8. 
Also, "pressing f8 as soon as you press enter after selecting win8 kernel " or for that matter any other key (Shift+F8, F2, F12 ) did not help.
Is there a way to get an option in the boot menu to boot into Windows 8 safe mode?

Found some similar posts, but could not find any relevant answers.

Thanks

Comment: ok..found an easy way. http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/  the second option titled "Getting To Safe Mode From Within Windows 8" helped

Comment: Look at the second answer at:
http://superuser.com/questions/408309/make-grub-2-boot-windows-8-safe-mode

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows 8 doesn't like giving people keyboard overrides at startup. And it's got a shiny new UI for entering safe mode.

Go to Settings>Advanced startup options . Scroll to the bottom and click the "restart now" button near "Advanced startup". Windows 8 will restart, and go into the shiny new UI I talked about. Click "troubleshoot", and then "restart". Your computer will restart again, and show another shiny UI for choosing the startup option. Type the number corresponding to safe mode (generally 4) and hit enter.

Nothing to do with GRUB. Win7 on GRUB lets me F8 into safe mode normally.